# Problems with file_exists() function

Tags: php

I have one page using this function to check if one file is on folder, recently i changed my server and the page started show some problems, i don't know why, but this verification not run well.

the code is:

```
$path ="../folder/file.tif";

if(file_exists($path)){
echo "file is ok";
}
```

Anyone ever had this problem?

Tks

Comment: Friends, I redid the permissions of all folders of my domain and the situation was normalized.


Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If safe_mode restrictions have been enabled on the server, you may run into trouble when the owner of the `folder` directory or the file itself is different than the one running PHP.

Comment: Friends, I redid the permissions of all folders of my domain and the situation was normalized.


Thank you all for your help

Comment: @Aline: In that case, please consider accepting my answer by clicking the checkbox icon to the left. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) on asking questions as well.